# I sent bitcoin from coinbase to my wallet, but it never got to my wallet. It says the transaction was completed. Can I get it back?

Tags: wallet

When I logged into my wallet, the bitcoin never showed up. Is there a way I can get the money back from Coinbase?

Answer (score 1):

If your wallet, says that the transaction is complete you can check its status: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/<replace_with_transaction_hash>

If you see that transaction got 6 confirmations or more and, isn' t reflected, at Coinbase you should contact support. I' m not a Coinbase user so don' t know about their deposit policy. You could probably find it in your deposit page